# Function to convert a value ex: 58K or 5m in a column into 58000 or 500000 in pandas

Tags: python

we have a column in a data frame, and some of the values are 5m or 5k, then I want to convert those values like 5000 and 5000000

```
def convert(x):
     col_number = 0
    if 'K' in x:
    col_number = int(x.replace('K', '')) * 1000
    elif 'k' in x:
    col_number = int(x.replace('k', '')) * 1000
     if 'M' in x:
    col_number = int(x.replace('M', '')) * 1000000
    elif 'm' in x:
    col_number = int(x.replace('m', '')) * 1000000
    else:
    col_number = int(x)
        return int(col_number)
```

Comment: Is this a question? If yes, please state clearly what the question needs to be? Also when sharing code use the code formatting, so others will be able to read it.

Comment: yes, problem statement is, we have a column in a data frame, and some of the values are 5m or 5k, then i want to convert those values as 5000 and 5000000.

Comment: I am saying please add that to the body of the question.

Comment: clearing question by adding the user's comment in the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with apply.

Here a running example:

```
import pandas as pd
x = {"number":["1000k","1000K","1M","1m"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)

def convert(number):
    number = number.lower()
    if "k" in number:
        return int(number.replace("k",""))*1000
    elif "m" in number:
        return int(number.replace("m","")) * 1000000
    return int(number)

df["converted"] = df["number"].apply(convert)
print(df)
```

## Output:

```
  number  converted
0  1000k  1000000
1  1000K  1000000
2     1M  1000000
3     1m  1000000
```